# Uniformly distributed pseudorandom integers inside CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda

How can I generate uniformly distributed pseudorandom integers within a kernel? As far as I know Curand Api allows to use poisson discrete distribution, but not uniform.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest two options within a Kernel:

1) using curand_uniform to obtain a random floating point number from a uniform distribution, then map it to integer interval:

```
float randu_f = curand_uniform(&localState);
randu_f *= (B-A+0.999999); // You should not use (B-A+1)*
randu_f += A;
int randu_int = __float2int_rz(randu_f);
```

__float2int_rz Convert the single-precision floating point value x to a signed integer in round-towards-zero mode.

*curand_uniform returns a sequence of pseudorandom floats uniformly distributed between 0.0 and 1.0. It may return from 0.0 to 1.0, where 1.0 is included and 0.0 is excluded.
You should use biggest_float_before_1 or a little less than 1, because there is a small chance You will random 1, and You can get out of bounds. I didn't also check does biggest_float_before_1 and floating-point operations on GPU guarantee not to exceed from defined bounds.

2) calling curand returns a sequence of pseudorandom numbers:

```
int randu_int = A + curand(&localState) % (B-A);
```

However, modulo is very expensive on GPU and method 1 is faster.