Cuda Large Block Number Causes Garbage Printf() Values
I'm generating some random image data in the following kernels:
(This process is described here)
__global__ void k_initRand(curandState *state, uint64_t seed){
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    curand_init(seed, tid, 0, &state[tid]);


}

__global__ void k_createColors(curandState *my_curandstate, int min, int max,  unsigned char * myGpuData, int startidx){
    int ti = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;

    float myrandf = curand_uniform(my_curandstate+ti + startidx);
    myrandf *= (max - min+0.999999);
    myrandf += min;
    
    int myrand = (int)truncf(myrandf);
    
    assert(myrand <= max);
    assert(myrand >= min);
    
    myGpuData[ti] = myrand;

    printf("INIT TI:%d\n", ti);

    
}


I launch the code like so:
    int colormin = 0;
    int colormax = 255;
    
    curandState *d_state;   
    cudaMalloc(&d_state, sizeof(curandState));

    unsigned char * d_R;
    cudaMalloc(&d_R, SIZE * sizeof(unsigned char) );

    k_initRand    <<< 191,     1024 >>>(  d_state, time(NULL)  );
    k_createColors<<< 64, 1024 >>>(  d_state, colormin, colormax,    d_R, 0 );

When I launch with these block sizes I'm getting garbage output from printf:
xz⑧:gτ*?A蓹搭?潷讀z⑧:gτ*?A蓹搭?潷讀z⑧:gτ*?A蓹搭?潷讀z⑧:gτ*?A蓹搭?潷讀z⑧:gτ*?A蓹搭?潷讀z⑧:gτ*?A蓹搭?潷讀z⑧:gτ*?A蓹

But when I launch it with both blocks at 1 the output is as expected
...
INIT TI:896
INIT TI:897
INIT TI:898
INIT TI:899
INIT TI:900
INIT TI:901
INIT TI:902
INIT TI:903
INIT TI:904
INIT TI:905
INIT TI:906
INIT TI:907
INIT TI:908
INIT TI:909
INIT TI:910
INIT TI:911
INIT TI:912
INIT TI:913
INIT TI:914
INIT TI:915
INIT TI:916
INIT TI:917
INIT TI:918
INIT TI:919
...

I check and am getting no errors:
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();        // Get error code
    printf("CUDA Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    if ( err != cudaSuccess ){
        printf("CUDA Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);

    }

I must run both kernels with block 1 to get correct output.
The code is still working correctly with the large block count but for some reason the kernel is printing garbage output.
I'm using Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 with Max-Q design
And I compile and launch from the command line like so:
nvcc -arch=sm_75 -o ppmer -ccbin "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" ppmwriter.cu > .\outputs\AA_CURRENT_ERROR.txt

ppmer > .\outputs\AA_CURRENT_OUTPUT.txt


this is not correct: cudaMalloc(&d_state, sizeof(curandState));  You need one state item in the array for each thread that will cover this indexing: float myrandf = curand_uniform(my_curandstate+ti + startidx);   There may be other issues.  You should be able to sort that one out just based on proper application of C++ principles, or study a curand sample code

@RobertCrovella that part actually works though. I'm writing random values into arrays, then fprinting into files and images are coming out correct. I don't know why it's effecting the printf output tho

the random code I got from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501081/generating-random-number-within-cuda-kernel-in-a-varying-range

Run your code with compute-sanitizer or cuda-memcheck and you should get errors. curand_uniform(my_curandstate+ti + startidx) (my_curandstate being a pointer to global memory) is clearly out of bounds given that you only allocate a single state. The output may still look random due do how the generator works. But it will modify these out of bounds memory locations and the locations used by printf are probably among those addresses which is why your output is randomized.

BTW it looks like you are not yet using the canonical CUDA runtime error macro. The error checking you posted looks like you are checking for launch failures (after launch, before synchronization). Are you also checking cudaDeviceSynchronize() or whatever CUDA runtime call triggers synchronization for you (could be cudaMemcpy() for example)? Because out of bounds accesses do normally trigger runtime errors without using a sanitizer. The sanitizers are just good to learn about yhe exact line in the kernel where it happens.

The answer you cite as source only launches a single thread, so it only needs a single state. While that answer could be improved by putting that implicit 1 into  the allocation as a named variable (or two for number of blocks and threads per block), it is technically correct.

@paleonix right that was a very simple fix (see answer) I got the seed/state values confused but random image output was basically identical. My error checking (including that canonical link you posted) also was only catching the illegal memory access when it ran WITH the printf in the kernel -- not without for some reason.

Problem was not enough memory in state array for thread/block size
    curandState * d_state;  
    cudaMalloc(&d_state, 195584 * sizeof(curandState) );

    k_initRand    <<< 191,     1024 >>>(  d_state, time(NULL)  );


For the kernel
    __global__ void k_initRand(curandState *state, uint64_t seed){
        int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        curand_init(seed, tid, 0, &state[tid]);

    }

Out of bounds error was garbling the printf() data
